# Problems with responsive drop down bar

Tags: css, responsive-design, anchor

i have started to put together a website, that uses a drop down menu in smaller sizes.

it is http://www.southmoorac.com/newindex.html

i have two pages working, the home age and the league page, but it's the drop down menu that is giving me problems, or should i say, viewing it on an iphone.

i have tested it on a pc, chrome developer tools, and it is working fine, but when view on an iphone that gives me a problem.

i have worked out that it is one line of code that is not working on the phone that is giving me the problem, so i'm looking for a work around.

this is the releveant html:

```css
.menu {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: left;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgba($dgreen, 0.99);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      transform: scale(1, 0);
      transition: 400ms;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
      transform-origin: top;
    
      &__box {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    
      &__list-item {
        @include letterspace(0.3rem);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        // padding: 6.2vh;
    
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(121, 122, 121, 0.301);
      }
    
      &__item-link {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    
        color: $orange;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2.2vh;
        padding-left: 20%;
        padding-right: 0;
    
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
          background-color: $orange;
          color: white;
        }
      }
```

```html
 <nav class="menu">
     <ul class="menu__box">
         <li class="menu__list-item"><a href="http://www.southmoorac.com/newindex.html"
          class="menu__item-link menu__active uncheck"><i
              class="fas fa-home   menu__icon"></i>Home</a>
         </li>    
         <li class="menu__list-item"><a href="#" class="menu__item-link  uncheck"><i
              class="fas fa-info menu__icon"></i>About Us</a>
                </li>    
         <li class="menu__list-item"><a href="#" class="menu__item-link uncheck"><i
              class="far fa-calendar-alt menu__icon uncheck"></i>Matches</a>
                </li>    
         <li class="menu__list-item"><a href="http://www.southmoorac.com/new_season_summary.php"
          class="menu__item-link uncheck"><i class="fas fa-trophy menu__icon ">
            </i>League
          Table</a>
         </li>    
         <li class="menu__list-item"><a href="#" class="menu__item-link uncheck"><i
              class="far fa-envelope-open menu__icon "></i>Contact Us</a>
                </li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
```

the code that is causing the problems is the height:100% line in the &__item-link.

the iphone just does not like it.

i have tried taking it out and using veritcal padding to gain height for the a link, but that's been like trying to nail jelly on a wall between different screen heights. it gets around the iphone display problem, but is not a real solution.

i hope you can help....

thanks

malcolm

Comment: Do you have this css `html, body { margin: 0; } .menu, .menu * { box-sizing: border-box; }` to have border and padding within the menu elements?

Comment: these are my defaults:

Comment: * {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

Comment: now sorted. how do i close down this question?